# CNN accuracy isn't accurate

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I have a cnn that looks like this

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.models import *
import random
import pickle
df = pd.read_csv('minor/age_gender.csv')
image_list = []
labels = []
image_labels = []
print(df.shape[0])
for x in range(df.shape[0]):
    png = np.fromstring(df.iloc[x]['pixels'], dtype=int, sep=' ').reshape((48,48,1))
    png = png/250.0
    age = df.iloc[x]['age']
    
    minor=None
    if int(age)<18:
        #print(2)
        minor =1
    else:

        minor = 0
    image_labels.append((png,minor))
young = []
old = []
for png,minor in image_labels:
    if minor==1:
        young.append((png,minor))
    else:
        old.append((png,minor))
pickle.dump(young,open('minor/young.pickle','wb'))
print('saved')
input()
young = young[:min(len(young),len(old))]
old = old[:min(len(young),len(old))]
print(len(young))
input()
image_labels = old+young
print(image_labels)
input()
random.shuffle(image_labels)
for png,minor in image_labels:
    image_list.append(png)
    print(minor)
    labels.append(minor)
    
image_list=np.array(image_list)
labels = np.array(labels)
print(image_list.shape)
#imag_list = image_list.reshape(-1,48,48,1)
print(image_list.shape)

def model2():
    inputs = Input((None,None,1))
    x = Conv2D(128,(5,5),input_shape = (48,48,1),padding='same')(inputs)
 
    x= BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(64,(5,5),padding='same')(x)
    
    x= BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)

    x= BatchNormalization()(x)
    x = Activation('relu')(x)
    x = Conv2D(1,(5,5),padding='same')(x)
    x=GlobalMaxPooling2D()(x)
    outputs = Activation('sigmoid')(x)
    model = Model(inputs=inputs,outputs=outputs)
    model.compile('adam','binary_crossentropy',metrics=['accuracy'])
    return model


input()
model = model2()
print(model.summary())
model.fit(image_list,labels,epochs=10,batch_size=32)
model.save('minor/age_detection6')
```

When I run it I get an epoch log looking like

```
Epoch 1/10
265/265 [==============================] - 40s 148ms/step - loss: 0.6445 - accuracy: 0.6447
Epoch 2/10
265/265 [==============================] - 37s 139ms/step - loss: 0.4422 - accuracy: 0.7994
Epoch 3/10
265/265 [==============================] - 37s 138ms/step - loss: 0.4186 - accuracy: 0.8168
Epoch 4/10
265/265 [==============================] - 37s 138ms/step - loss: 0.3720 - accuracy: 0.8381
Epoch 5/10
265/265 [==============================] - 37s 138ms/step - loss: 0.3559 - accuracy: 0.8517
Epoch 6/10
265/265 [==============================] - 39s 149ms/step - loss: 0.3487 - accuracy: 0.8564
Epoch 7/10
265/265 [==============================] - 40s 151ms/step - loss: 0.3341 - accuracy: 0.8597
Epoch 8/10
265/265 [==============================] - 37s 139ms/step - loss: 0.3252 - accuracy: 0.8699
Epoch 9/10
265/265 [==============================] - 37s 139ms/step - loss: 0.3084 - accuracy: 0.8765
Epoch 10/10
265/265 [==============================] - 37s 138ms/step - loss: 0.3074 - accuracy: 0.8746
```

All is good up to this point. There is a fairly high accuracy rate. Here's where it gets weird. In the following code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model
import pandas as pd
import pickle
from tqdm import tqdm
model = load_model('minor/age_detection6')
df = pd.read_csv('minor/age_gender.csv')
image_list = []
labels = []

print(df.shape[0])
for x in range(df.shape[0]):
    png = np.fromstring(df.iloc[x]['pixels'], dtype=int, sep=' ').reshape((48,48,1))
    png = png/250.0
    age = df.iloc[x]['age']
    
    minor=None
    if int(age)<18:
        minor =1
    else:
        minor = 0
    image_list.append(png)
    labels.append(minor)
print(labels.index(1))
input()
image2 = cv2.imread('minor/kid.png')
print(image2.shape)
image2 = cv2.cvtColor(image2,cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
print(image2.shape)
image = image_list[0]
print(labels[0])
image = image/255.0
image = np.reshape(image,(1,image.shape[0],image.shape[1],1))
image2 = image2/255.0
image2 = np.reshape(image2,(1,image2.shape[0],image2.shape[1],1))
print(image2.shape)
input()
valu = 0
predictions=model.predict(image)
print(predictions)
for items in predictions:
    for item in items:
        valu+=item
valu = int(valu/predictions.shape[0])
print(valu)
print(labels[0])
young = pickle.load(open('minor/young.pickle','rb'))
print('no')
score = 0
for png,minor in tqdm(young):
    score += int(model.predict(png)[0][0])
print(score/len(young))
```

I take a bunch of pictures of minors(some of which the model has trained on) but when predicting all of them there is a 0% success rate. However on the non-minors it's 100%. My data was shuffled and evened out so I'm perplexed as to why this is happening. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: NOT SURE, but why is your output just a sigmoid activation. Shouldn't it be `outputs = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(x)`?

Comment: @AdarshWase Then it wouldn't be a Fully Connected CNN. The whole point of the project is to create a FCN

Comment: This isn't strictly true as a dense layer is equivalent to a 1x1 convolution layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally in binary prediction, you set a threshold with which you separate the output into two classes. You are just trying to put your outputs (a number between 0 and 1) into your classes without thresholding. Your comparison should look something like this:

```
class_1_correct += np.sum(outputs>=0.5 * class_labels)
class_0_correct += np.sum(np.abs(1 - outputs<0.5 * class_labels))
```

This is just an example and will need to be moulded to your code.

Furthermore, this part is wrong:

```
for png,minor in tqdm(young):
    score += int(model.predict(png)[0][0])
```

You are casting your sigmoid output to an int, which will almost always equal zero.

The same applies to this code:

```
valu = int(valu/predictions.shape[0])
```

which I think you want to be:

```
valu = int(valu/predictions.shape[0]*100)
```